# SignTool.exe equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a Powershell script to replicate what `signtool.exe` does. I'm using it on an Installer exe.

I found that `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` handles the signing of the file with a certificate, but I'm also looking for the `signtool` feature that signs an ActiveX control on the file.

```
SignTool sign /f MyCert.pfx /t timestampURL /du "webpageURL" /d "mycompany" MyInstaller.exe
```

`Set-AuthenticodeSignature` is able to handle the `/f` and `/t` parameters with `-Certificate` and `-TimestampServer` respectively.

So my question is, is there a cmdlet that handles the `/d` and `/du`?

Referencing the SignTool page:

> The following command signs an ActiveX control and provides information that is displayed by Internet Explorer when the user is prompted to install the control:
>
> ```
> SignTool sign /f MyCert.pfx /d "My Product Name" /du "http://www.example.com/my_product/info.html" MyControl.exe
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent for a description or a URL within the Powershell Cmdlet `Set-AuthenticodeSignature`.

You can, however, still call Signtool from Powershell if having a URL is important for your product.  I would approach the problem with the call operator like so:

```
$signString = 'Signtool.exe sign /f MyCert.pfx /d "My Product Name" /du "http://www.example.com/my_product/info.html" MyControl.exe'
& $signString
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `C:\"Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit"\signtool.exe`

If you already have pfx installed on the machine then:

`C:\"Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit"\signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 myexe.exe`

If you already haven't installed pfx  on the machine then:

`C:\"Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit"\signtool.exesign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword /fd SHA256 MyFile.exe`

---