# signtool /d equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: code-signing, signtool

I am signing .MSI files using Powershell `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet. My goal is to use this cmdlet to replace signtool. However, I am not seeing a parameter that I can specify a description to the signed content, just like the `/d` option in `signtool`. Is there a way to specify this using pure Powershell? If not, is there any other alternative that can replace `signtool`? For some reason, we found that `signtool` is less stable than `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` and we would like to ditch it.

Comment: Basically the same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649825/signtool-exe-equivalent-in-powershell